# My app has been copied

Tags: android

I found out that someone has copied my app name, and also almost all its functions!
Now, my app has not a lot of downloads, but however this makes me really angry! is there something i can do to remove it from the google play store?

yes i know that marketing works like that, but its  name is exactly the same of mine... 
this is my app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mrMr.funny.metronome&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5tck1yLmZ1bm55Lm1ldHJvbm9tZSJd

this is the other 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.miidio.urbeats&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5taWlkaW8udXJiZWF0cyJd

Comment: Add links to both apps, I'd like to see that.

Comment: No. AFAIK, you can do nothing. Because I found millions of apps and games with same functionalities.

Comment: That should encourage you to write an even greater application. One should not think of software in terms of 'mine' and 'copyrighted', it's not future.

Comment: You must work for free Alexander Kulyakhtin?   So when your not writing code for free, it's not yours after all, do you go out and beg for money for food and shelter?

Answer (score 4):

I would like to report my experience. I was looking for an app to look for an Italian tax information about vehicles, I found some and all of them sucked a lot. So I decided to write down another better one. Now it's the most downloaded one (among them) and it provides more functionalities and is more appealing.

So, why someone else shouldn't try to improve what you offer? That's simple market.

Comment: What you're talking about is different.  It's different to create something better than to copy verbatim the layout and functionality of an app.  You're not adding any value, just STEELING.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do within the Play Store.

The only way you could block another app with the same name and functions would be (in US) if you had a trademark registered on the name, or a patent registered for the functionality.

There is nothing within the the 'Terms of Service' of the store that would prohibit someone from copying your app (or functionality) - or any recourse for you to get it removed.

You can try to effect the other app (give it one star reviews, leave a comment in the ratings saying "this is just a copy of the better app named...", etc).

Bottom line you have no recourse to have the app removed - sorry.

Comment: Well said Booger.  This is a major flaw for Android.  I'm focusing more on Apple here on out because of this.